# Flex ItemRenderer Example Troubles, what am I doing wrong

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, checkbox, itemrenderer

Hello to whomever wishes to help me.

I'm trying to implement this example:
http://ramblingdeveloper.com/ramblings/2011/9/24/creating-a-flex-spark-list-of-checkbox-bound-to-xml-dataprov.html

My example is fairly the same with a few small differences which I modified the whole code accordingly.

My MXML Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
<fx:XML format="e4x" id="namesXML">
    <people>
        <person>
            <name>Leon</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Mathilda</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Stansfield</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Benny</name>
        </person>
    </people>
</fx:XML>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

        var temp:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(namesXML.children());
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List itemRenderer="CheckBoxItemRenderer"
        dataProvider="{temp}"/>
```

and my MXML ItemRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true">

<s:CheckBox label="{data.person.name}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I keep getting a Null Object Reference and have been messing around with where I think the problem is:

```
<s:CheckBox label="{data.person.name}"/>
```

Which is how I'm accessing my XML data, but I'm not 100% sure since XML and XML traversal isn't my strongest point. Any small insight would help while I sit and keep tweaking it on my end for a breakthrough.

EDIT: Fixed the ItemRenderer code, was missing the closing tag.
EDIT #2: The name of my ItemRenderer file is CheckBoxItemRenderer like the example has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer - since namesXML is declared in the <fx:Declarations> section, it is a child of your main application, and isn't instantiated until later (when all the children are created).

If you want to leave namesXML defined as you have, I'd suggest adding a creationComplete handler and setting temp at that time:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   creationComplete="doInit()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
           import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

            var temp:XMLListCollection;

            protected function doInit():void {
                temp = new XMLListCollection(namesXML.children());
            }
        ]]>
   </fx:Script>
```

Another problem is that temp needs to be marked as Bindable - otherwise, when it gets set the changes won't cause the List to redisplay.

Finally, the XMLNode items in temp are already person nodes, so you only need to specify data.name in the item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true">

<s:CheckBox label="{data.name}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Great catch on the temp not being Bindable.  I think the rest of what you say is inaccurate.  I think that namesXML should be initialized after the constructor but before the createChildren() is execute; which means it should have a value.  Of course, I'm not sure if namesXML is initialized before the temp variable.  I wonder if `dataProvider="{namesXML}"` is what is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But what you suggested did allow me to get the example working and fixed the null pointer I was getting with namesXML.children(). Also thanks for the clarification with the fx:declaration tag, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer; but it is too big for a comment.  To help debug; instead of using Binding in the ItemRenderer use the dataChange event:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true" dataChange="onDataChange()>

<fx:Script>
<[[
 protected function onDataChange():void{
   // if data isn't defined; just perform a return here
   if(!data){ return }
   // try a lot of traces to see what comes out
   trace(data);
   trace(data.name);
   trace(data.person);
   trace(data.person.name);
   // etc.,. etc..
   var checkBoxLabel :String = data.person.name;
   check.label = checkBoxLabel;
 }
]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:CheckBox id="check" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I am not an expert at XML parsing either.  I have found that watch variables in the Flash Builder Debug panel are inconsistent / unhelpful in drilling down into XML; so the trace statements are the way to go.

IF I had to guess; the data is equal to a single person, like this:

```
<person>
    <name>Benny</name>
</person>
```

So, doing data.person is probably redundant and tries to drill down too far resulting in the null value.  data.name seems more likely; in my mind.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Went to get lunch. But thanks for the tip. I tried it out however it appears the problem is namesXML.children().

Apparently it is null since I cannot even do a trace on namesXML.toString().

Comment: Yes, if names.XML is null; that will be a problem.  I'm unclear why that would be the case given the code you've shared.